# Fourier Transform of triangle function

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I have a question regarding the FT of the triangular function:

[image]

How does $e^{-j\omega t}$ becomes the cosine function in the first line?

What happened to the sine when you go from $e^{j \omega t}$ to $cos(\omega t) + j*sin(\omega t)$

[image]

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: This is because $\sin \omega t$ is an odd function. The integral on $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ cancel out.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that... thank you.